# How to use shellCommandProceccesor in Spring-XD job

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-batch, spring-xd

In SPring XD there is a common module to run shell command using the Shell Command Processor .

[Spring Common Processor Module Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/modules/common/shell-command-processor.xml)

I wanna leverage shell Command in my Spring-XD composed job before starting the main job (which is sequence of MR/Hive/Pig programs). Is there any way to achieve this in XD-job not by creating streams.

I couldn't find any tasklet for running shell/bash scripts to leverage in my xd-job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `shell` processor module available OOTB.
You can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#shell) for more detail.

Comment: I wanna use the module in job but its not showing in the job module

Comment: when I add the shell processor to the job module I am getting below erroe message in the logs  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Job module doesn't have output channel set.
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.AbstractJobPlugin.getOutputChannelName(AbstractJobPlugin.java:49)

Comment: You could setup a stream that triggers the job. Something like this: "trigger | shell > <job-input-queue"

Comment: Documentation for that is here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#_launching_a_job